# Vanity: one experiment per user

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, redis, vanity

I just installed Vanity with redis. I've added multiple experiments on one page. But when a user is visiting the page, he is seeing all the experiments.

How can I make sure that a user will only see one experiment and that Vanity chooses which experiment the user will see?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how Vanity could be configured to show the default for all but 1 experiment on a given page.

Currently Vanity experiments are independent of each other, so there's no notion of "being shown to the same user at the same time". This [Github issue](https://github.com/assaf/vanity/issues/147) looks like it's tracking a related feature request.